# How do IoT devices listen to the Tangle?

Tags: internet-of-things

I've seen examples of IoT devices pushing data onto the tangle, such as open source Ruuvi tag, but how do IoT devices listen for events and MAM subscriptions on the tangle. Would the IoT device have to continuously make findTransaction calls to the API host, in intervals decided by the programmer (e.g. every 10 seconds)?

Comment: IMO, this question isn't really iota specific. Basically it can be reduced to "what kind of strategy can be used to achieve almost real-time remote control on a low-resource-iot-device with poor/unpredictable network connection?" (see also https://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The range of IoT devices is huge. Unless you specify the target group of devices a lot this is just guesswork.

Comment: IoT devices that don't have the resources to host a Node/API

Comment: In Ethereum, devices listen for Events with NodeJS. The alternative to NodeJS is for the IoT devices to make a call to the API every 15 seconds,checking for state changes, because that's how often the blocks update. But since IOTA is continuously updating... The only other solution I can think of it programming the full node to listen to all transactions, filter out transactions I'm interested, and the node will contact out to the IoT device if the transaction regards that device

Answer (score 0):

The [Development Roadmap](https://blog.iota.org/iota-development-roadmap-74741f37ed01) mentions IoT-Devices in the following manner:

> C++
>
> This client is our highest priority at the moment, as we are
> currently porting IRI over to C++ and plan to continue core
> development in this language. Unlike Java it does not require a
> Virtual Machine installed on the devices in order to to run code and
> it compiles to machine code in real time, making it a lot more
> suitable for these resource restrained IoT devices. It’s also one of
> the most supported and typed languages in the world.

The [GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/iotaledger) does not contain a C++ client, which would be that "highest priority client".

ATM you'll have to use a Gateway (Message Broker). See [this article](https://learn.iota.org/tutorial/storing-mqtt-messages-on-the-tangle) (Storing MQTT messages on the Tangle
) on *learn.iota.org* which refers to [this Message Broker](https://github.com/nicoschtein/iota-mqtt-poc)

Using such a Message Broker is an acceptable solution, since it's much more troubling to update the firmware when changes need to be done (new seed, change addresses and so on) than the code on the broker. So, for a beginning, this would be the way to go.

<del>It's up to you to see if the [JS client](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js) can run on a device like a [Particle Photon](https://www.particle.io/products/hardware/photon-wifi-dev-kit). If you test it and know the result, it would be great if you share it here.</del>